# How do I copy existing formset data to prepopulate a CreateView in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In one of my views, I use a class based CreateView to prepopulate my form with various fields from a different model.

I do so like shown below:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(Author, self).get_initial()
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get("dropdown"))
    initial = Book.__dict__.copy()

    initial.update({
              "pages": book.pages,
    return initial
```

Works brilliantly.  Now I'm trying to grab data from some related formsets for this model as well, but because they are formsets, I'm a bit stumped on how to go about doing the prepopulation in as close to an identical fashion as possible.  They are inline formsets.  I've spent the last day looking and can't find anything that is helping me think this through.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts on this.

Comment: What does mean "related formsets"? Could make an example?

Comment: Simply put....I'm trying to populate a formset with a queryset.  Just can't quite make out the approach.  Still looking.